# Volume enclosed between a cone and a sphere

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Find the volume between the cone $z = 2\cos \theta $ and the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$.

For this problem, I have considered that the radius of the sphere is $2$. But after that, I am not quite sure how to set the limits of integration.

I have tried graphing the problem and it shows a displaced cone. I am not sure how this affects my limits either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It appears you are mixing coordinate systems. What is the relationship between $\theta$ and $x,y$? Are you using the standard $\tan \theta = \dfrac{y}{x}$?

Comment: I think that's the case. But I am not sure how to proceed afterwards. Should I work in spherical coordinates?

Comment: How $z = 2\cos \theta$ is a cone?

Comment: @DiegoL. can you link a wolframalpha plot of the cone?

Comment: Yet another cone-and-sphere volume exercise. Look through the handy list of related problems at right. You’ll find a bunch of similar or even identical problems there.

Comment: That's not a cone...